# Casting a float attribut with ado.net and razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ado.net

I have an asp.net mvc application in which i have this function :

```
public List<FichierModels> GetFichiersFromDirectoy(int _id_dir)
{
    List<FichierModels> l = new List<FichierModels>();
    Data.Connect();
    using (Data.connexion)
    {
        string queryString = @"select Id, Id_directory, Url, Upload_date, Last_download, Downloads_count, Taille, Expiration_date, Name from Fichier where Id_directory = @Id_directory ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Data.connexion);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_directory", _id_dir);
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            do
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    FichierModels fichier = new FichierModels();
                    fichier.Id = reader.GetInt32(0); 
                        fichier.Id_directory = reader.GetInt32(1);
                        fichier.Url = reader.GetString(2); 
                        fichier.Upload_date = reader.GetDateTime(3); 
                        fichier.Last_download = reader.GetDateTime(4);
                        fichier.Downloads_count = reader.GetInt32(5); 
                        fichier.Taille = reader.GetFloat(6); 
                        fichier.Expiration_date = reader.GetDateTime(7);
                        fichier.Name = reader.GetString(8) ;
                    l.Add(fichier);

                }
            } while (reader.NextResult());

            return l;

        }
        catch { return null; }

    }
}
```

[image: schema]
The problem is that an exception of casting in the line `fichier.Taille = reader.GetFloat(6);` however the attribute `taille` is float and in the class `Fichier` also.but always an exception of incorrect cast.
[image: record]
Why this happens? how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the exact exception you're getting? Can you show the class FichierModels?

Comment: ` public class FichierModels
    {
        private int _id;
        private int _id_directory;
        private string _url;
        private DateTime _upload_date;
        private DateTime _last_download;
        private int _downloads_count;
        private float _taille;
        private DateTime _expiration_date;
        private string _name;

        
`

Comment: Is it possible that the data reader cannot convert the source data from column `Tallie` into a float? What does your data schema look like?

Comment: @Jay i am using sql server dbms , see the picture plz

Comment: Can you verify the specific record your reading is not null? Otherwise I'm not sure it all looks fine to me.

Comment: Very odd indeed. Can you post the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MSSQL float should be a double in C#. The default precision of a float in MSSQL is double precision (when a column is defined as *float* it is actually a *float(53)* ), while a float in C# always has single precision.

Answer (score 1):

The float type in Sql server is the Double type in C#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx